# What's the equivalent of using `select()` with `text()` using the ORM?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

My distant goal is using a MySQL full text index ... but the proximate issue is combining usage of `text` with the SQLAlchemy ORM.

Suppose we've got a `User` class inheriting from the declarative base and a full text index defined on the MySQL column `name`. Here's what works:

```
from sqlalchemy import text

full_text = text('MATCH(name) AGAINST(\":name\") > :value')
filter_arg = full_text.params(name="John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt", value=1)
session.query(User).filter(filter_arg)
```

As stated in the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#using-literal-sql), using `text` with `filter` and `order_by` is straightforward. I want to actually select the values though. I want to do what this totally bogus code seems like it should achieve:

```
full_text = text('MATCH(name) AGAINST(\":name\")')
value = full_text.params(name="John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt") 
session.query(User, value)
```

That doesn't work, obviously, but I hope it's clear enough to imply the goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Column.match`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.match) function should do the job:

```
xpr = User.name.match("John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt").label("match_result")
q = session.query(User, xpr)
```

In fact, the whole query including the where clause is much better expressed without using `text()`:

```
xpr = User.name.match("John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt").label("match_result")
q = session.query(User, xpr).filter(xpr > 1)
```

Comment: Also this extension might be useful: https://github.com/mengzhuo/sqlalchemy-fulltext-search

Comment: I had not known about Column.match, but it appears to only operate in Boolean mode for MySQL. So I cannot get, or filter against, a specific value. I will look at the extension.

Comment: I am not an expert of full text search, but boolean mode is the way to structure the query, and as you specified it, it would be exactly match agains single values. From the docs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html): `(no operator)

By default (when neither + nor - is specified) the word is optional, but the rows that contain it are rated higher. This mimics the behavior of MATCH() ... AGAINST() without the IN BOOLEAN MODE modifier.`

Comment: Okay, I think you're right that it should work. There's a problem somewhere in SQLAlchemy though, because it's trying to cast the real valued score as a Boolean. For a query that gives a non-zero match, I get an the error `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3523, in proc
    return row[column]
ValueError: int_to_boolean only accepts None, 0 or 1`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer, for the MySQL backend you may need the following workaround.

```
from sqlalchemy import type_coerce, Float
result = session.query(User, type_coerce(xpr, Float)).all()
```

[Source](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3263/valueerror-on-fulltext-match-in-mysql)